# Convert a pandas dataframe into a nested dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dataframe that I would like to convert into a nested dictionary.  For example:

df =

| ID | Action | Responsible | Phase |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.1 | Request Document | Project Manager | 1.0 Create Document Request |
| 2.1 | Create course module | Writer | 2.0 Create Document |
| 2.2 | Send module for review | Writer | 2.0 Create Document |
| 3.1 | Publish Course | Reviewers | 3.0 Publish Document |
| 3.2 | Address feedback | Writer | 3.0 Publish Document |

Ultimately, I need to turn it into a nested dictionary that is something like this:

```
context = {'Section': 

[{'Phase': '1.0 Create Document',
   'Activity': [
            {'Responsible': 'Project Manager', 'ID': '1.1', 'Action': 'Request Document'},
            ],
        }, 
 {'Phase': '2.0 Create Document',
  'Activity': [
            {'Responsible': 'Writer', 'ID': '2.1', 'Action': 'Create course module'},
            {'Responsible': 'Writer', 'ID': '2.2', 'Action': 'Send module for review'},    
        ],
        },
{'Phase': '3.0 Publish Document',
  'Activity': [
            {'Responsible': 'Reviewers', 'ID': '3.1', 'Action': 'Publish course'},
            {'Responsible': 'Writer', 'ID': '3.2', 'Action': 'Address Feedback'},    
        ],
        }    
],
}
```

I've thought of using `df.groupby` and `to_dict` and a `lambda` function, but I haven't figured out how to get it to work

(Sorry, I know this isn't the cleanest code or example; I'm still learning)

EDIT:

The code I have tried is:

```
context = df.groupby('Phase')[['ID','Action','Responsible','Note','Output']].apply(lambda x: x.set_index('ID').to_dict(orient='index')).to_dict()
```

but that provides the wrong output as it doesn't give the right keys for the dictionary.  And as I think about it, what I really need to do is create nested lists inside a dictionary, matched to the right key, grouped by the 'Phase'

Comment: As per the expected output, I think the better way would be to have the custom function which will convert the pandas dataframe to this expected output.

Comment: @TonyMontana Completely agree. I just can't figure it out though

Comment: Well, you may start with a function in which you'll loop through the dataframe and as per your requirement you'll create the dictionary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `to_dict` within groupby, then use `to_dict` on the result again to get nested records:

```
data = (df.drop('Phase', axis=1) 
          .groupby(df['Phase'])
          .apply(lambda x: x.to_dict(orient='r'))
          .reset_index(name='Activity')
          .to_dict(orient='r'))

context = {'Section': data}
print(context)
```

```
{'Section': [{'Activity': [{'Action': 'Request Document',
                            'ID': 1.1,
                            'Responsible': 'Project Manager'}],
              'Phase': '1.0 Create Document Request'},
             {'Activity': [{'Action': 'Create course module',
                            'ID': 2.1,
                            'Responsible': 'Writer'},
                           {'Action': 'Send module for review',
                            'ID': 2.2,
                            'Responsible': 'Writer'}],
              'Phase': '2.0 Create Document'},
             {'Activity': [{'Action': 'Publish Course',
                            'ID': 3.1,
                            'Responsible': 'Reviewers'},
                           {'Action': 'Address feedback',
                            'ID': 3.2,
                            'Responsible': 'Writer'}],
              'Phase': '3.0 Publish Document'}]}
```